# Значение указателей и ссылок в стеке C++

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Возьмем к примеру код:

```
int x = 5;
int* ref = &x;
int& ref2 = x;
```

Стек программы:

| Адресс | Значение | Переменная |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000002900F5FC44 | 5 | x |
| 0000002900F5FC68 | 0000002900F5FC44 | *ref |
| ? | ? | &ref2 |

Мой вопрос в том, что именно хранится на местах '?'.

Или другой пример:

```
int smth() {
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}

int& smth2() {
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}
```

Функция smth после своего выполнения положит на верхушку стека значение 5.
Что будет на верхушке стека после вызова функции smth2?

Comment: В плане реализации (поведения программы) ссылки ничем не отличаются от указателей.

Comment: Как-то далековато для такой программы лежат `x` и `ref`. Давайте конкретные данные (и укажите, какой комп, ОС и компайлер)

Comment: Ссылка `int& ref2` имеет автоматическое место хранения, и оно **не** обязано храниться в стеке. Реальное представление ссылки зависит от компилятора.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ваши собственные попытки ответа. В противном случае его закроют как учебный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

первый случай - а кто его знает. компилятор может представить ссылку как указатель и сохранить в стеке, тогда там будет скорее всего 0000002900F5FC44. А может оптимизировать и выбросить переменную. На усмотрение компилятора.

> Функция smth после своего выполнения положит на верхушку стека значение 5.

неверно. Не после, а во время своего выполнения. А после своего выполнения там может быть все что угодно. Абсолютно.

> Что будет на верхушке стека после вызова функции smth2?

А вот тут вообще нет смысла об этом рассуждать. Вы возвращаете ссылку на локальную переменную. А это UB. После выполнения такого кода компилятор имеет право делать все, что ему покажется правильным, например, записать туда 10. Имеет право.

Comment: Тактика оптимизации для указателей и для ссылок одинакова. Я к тому что оптимизатор и указатель может удалить.

Comment: компилятор может вообще всю функцию заинлайнить или переработать код так, что его уже не узнать. А если там ещё и UB...

Comment: А что у него во второй функции return x; будет возвращать ссылку из-за того, что функция объявлена возвращающей ссылку? Почему не значение переменной x?

Comment: @xmikex, будет возвращена ссылка (на несуществующую переменную). Значение нельзя возвращать, так как требуется возвращать именно ссылку.

Comment: @KoVadim, последняя функция ещё не UB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649320/14775762

Comment: ну как бы да. Но вызывать функцию и не использовать возвращаемое ей значение ещё то поведение

Comment: Хорошо, если бы переменная x была глобальной и в методе возвращалась бы ссылка на нее, то в стек был бы записан адрес переменной x? Тогда при обращении к результату метода программа бы обращалась к этому адресу?

Comment: а какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить? обвести вокруг пальца компилятор? - наивно. пройти собеседование?

Comment: Просто для себя интересуюсь, если я пишу на языке, то я должен понимать, как он работает, хотя бы основные концепции. Всю жизнь писал на шарпе и универ заставил подучить плюсы, вот пытаюсь разобраться, как тут все устроено.

Comment: @ЕгорЛазеба, для понимания, `"как он работает"` полезно смотреть ассемблерный код, который умеет делать компилятор. Можно  получать его с разными опциями (в основном, уровнями оптимизации) и сравнивать. Например, `gcc -S t.c` выведет ассемблерный код в файл `t.s`

Comment: а лучше вообще на godbolt.org